# swiprolog map false to zero and true to one

Tags: prolog, logic

How can i map in swi-prolog true and false to 1's and 0's respectively?
i need to evaluate ones and zeroes like true and falses (like in truth tables).
i am having some difficulties since whenever i try to use 1 as logical value swi-prolog dosent take it kindly and returns erros.

I would like to try something like this

```
0 :- false.
1 :- true.
```

and when i query my logical "and" operation, it should return **logical and** operation applied to both values.

```
? my_and_operation(1, 0).
false

? my_and_operation(1, 1).
true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple way to do what you need is just determine some `isTrue/1` and `isFalse/1` predicates.

```
isTrue( 1 ).
isFalse( 0 ).

booleanAnd( X, Y ) :-
    isTrue( X ),
    isTrue( Y ).
```

Usage.

```
?- booleanAnd( 1, 0 ).
false.

?- booleanAnd( 1, 1 ).
true.
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could do something like :

```
map(1, true).
map(0, false).

boolAnd(X, Y) :-
    maplist(map, [X, Y], [A, B]),
    (A, B).

boolOr(X, Y) :-
    maplist(map, [X, Y], [A, B]),
    (A; B).
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpler way:

```
my_and_operation(X, Y) :-
 X == 1, Y == 1.
```

Comment: (==)/2 is not monotonic: With your definition, for example the query my_and_operation(X, Y) FAILS although there clearly is a solution, an indeed the more SPECIFIC query my_and_operation(1, 1) succeeds. If possible, keep your programs monotonic, as it allows for declarative debugging and easier reasoning about properties, so define it for example as my_and_operation(1, 1).

Comment: I think the best way is just to use constraints, for example with library(clpfd): X #/\ Y, and X #\/ Y for "and" and "or", respectively. This works in all directions and often leads to a smaller search space.

Comment: @mat: I initially wrote the answer (in my mind) with the unify: my_and_operation(X, Y) :- X = 1, Y = 1 (surely simpler at least for char count!). I'm aware of some of the implications of ==/2, but i tought that the OP, espressing such basic question, probably is not interested in these.  Mog: I don't understand your comment: i'd write my_or_operation like X = 1 ; Y = 1...

Answer (score 0):

The really simple solution:

```
my_and_operation(1, 1).
```